# Property not found in disjoint union type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

The following code:

```
/* @flow */

type StepApplicationAction = { type: "STEP_APPLICATION" }
type RewindApplicationAction = { type: "REWIND_APPLICATION" }

type ApplicationAction = StepApplicationAction | RewindApplicationAction

type RequestVinsAction = { type: "REQUEST_VINS" }
type ReceiveVinsAction = { type: "RECEIVE_VINS", vins: Array<string> }

type VehicleAction = RequestVinsAction | ReceiveVinsAction

type Action = ApplicationAction | VehicleAction

function reducer(action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "REQUEST_VINS": console.log('HERE')
    case "RECEIVE_VINS":
      console.log(action.vins)
    default:
      return
  }
}
```

Produces these errors:

```
19:       console.log(action.vins)
                         ^ property `vins`. Property not found in
19:       console.log(action.vins)
                  ^ object type
```

Not sure what's wrong with my disjoint union setup in this example.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to `return` or `break` from within the case branch:

```
/* @flow */

type StepApplicationAction = { type: "STEP_APPLICATION" }
type RewindApplicationAction = { type: "REWIND_APPLICATION" }

type ApplicationAction = StepApplicationAction | RewindApplicationAction

type RequestVinsAction = { type: "REQUEST_VINS" }
type ReceiveVinsAction = { type: "RECEIVE_VINS", vins: Array<string> }

type VehicleAction = RequestVinsAction | ReceiveVinsAction

type Action = ApplicationAction | VehicleAction

function reducer(action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "REQUEST_VINS": console.log('HERE'); return;
//                                            ^^^^^^^
    case "RECEIVE_VINS":
      console.log(action.vins); return;
    default:
      return;
  }
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKGeOAgjjjAJYDGAhhtXAHZm1OtgC8YA3mGz4AXGABEhACoBRAAoB9MrNkAZAJIBhMpLUB5AHJiwAX0y4CAJTwJqLACYUqdRszYdXPfoPOixF6QDqavoAIorK6lo6BkamZvhgjjQMnG6pnsSkSc6p7OkAPmBWNvbZKa55ruhClngAjgCueADOGABqts2VXLwCNb7+AIoAqtJS8m3BhLHxtbR41ABueB0sXe49Xv3i-hrSam3SE1NiADRgi52iZABON-RYADytN7YA5gB8JtXmYG14AAs6DA8N0WJ4rI0Wu1OmCwIUrPMlitYRsWD8EnDeGUXKw4YV-kDaCCwegoA0WGiwDc8HYGvMbgAKeho65ogCU-FQYDAzRsGFoALAzLRADoapy+NyeWAGM0CH5pCMxpJjvppqJaKxmnAQaL4G9GQByAAS0n8RvZAG5qXgMA0biwrahgMAZe6PZ6vd6fTyAHoBwN+6U8uUK3b7Q5qjUhmVata6vD6uCGlmpUWXNbW232x3O912PBQegNGAYYSxnk03NO6WmYxAA)